# How do I set up the App.Config for my UserControl?

Tags: user-controls, config

I'm developing a UserControl in a Winform application in VS2010.  I did this inside a UserControlLibrary project as it seemed logical.  However, when I run, the App.Config that I have in that project is not being read at all, which is causing all kinds of problems.

Is there a different way I'm supposed to do App.Config's in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

individual controls don't have their own App.Config.  The app.config of the executing program that hosts the control is used (or the web.config if you're using asp.net).  You need to copy the settings out of the user controls config and put them in the config for the winform project.

Comment: The problem is that there IS no other project.  I created a UCL project and started building my control inside it.  When I hit Run, it fires up the Test Container (which is a neat little tool you get for free) with my control embedded in it.  As soon as I try to do something with the database, though, it bombs because the connection string doesn't exist.

Comment: Never heard of that before - interesting.  There must be an exe somewhere for the test container - it should have a corresponding config (or you can try creating one).

Answer (score 0):

copy all keys you want from `app.config` file of `UserControlLibrary` project into `app.config` of your `winform` application

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to load any app.config file during design time user control load. You can prevent the need to though by wrapping your user control load methods with:

```
private void myUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
        //....stuff
    }            
}
```